# Why are functions synchronous in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
console.log("start")
myfunc()
console.log("end")

function myfunc(){
  for(i=0; i<100000000; i++){

  }
  console.log("this should be the end")
}
```

The output of the code is always:

```
start
this should be the end
end
```

Should myfunc() execute in node and take longer, so that "end" should be invoked earlier because javascript is asynchronous?

Comment: No, why should it? JavaScript is synchronous.

Comment: JavaScript isn't asynchronous, where did you get that information from?

Comment: I thought it so asynchronous and that is why promises exists

Comment: JavaScript has asynchronous features, but those need to be used explicitly. Not everything is executed asynchronous

Comment: Many libraries/frameworks/environments JavaScript interacts with expose themselves asynchronously, like Node.js' file system interaction and browsers' HTTP interaction.

Comment: @David what you have here is a synchronous for loop, meaing `myfunc()` will return after the loop has completed. For this to behave in the way you are expecting, you'd need to explicitly use Promises/async/await (ie run the loop in an async function)

Comment: Javascript **code** is always synchronous. But some low level functionality like network and disk I/O are asynchronous to avoid blocking other code. Javascript is not special in this regard, it is exactly the same as C, C++, Java, Python etc. The only exception is that javascript either does not have or strongly discourage synchronous I/O

Comment: @slebetman python always waits for my http request, javascript does not

Comment: @David well JavaScript and Python are quite different as far as I/O operations go

Comment: @David That's because Python allows you to do both synchronous and asynchronous I/O. Use Python's Twisted framework with non-blocking http request and you will find that Python does not "always" wait for your requests

Comment: @Pointy Javascript works like Python's Twisted framework

Comment: @David Checkout https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to make http requests in Python the same way you'd make in Javascript. Asynchronous I/O is not new. It was invented in the 60s (yes, even before DOS). What's new is a language that **forces** you to use it

Comment: @slebetman sure, though that's probably not in the OP's range of experience.

Comment: @Pointy not yet, but it helps to see what is out there

Comment: Note that javascript (and by association node.js) claim to fame, it's supposed speed, is all due to pervasive asynchronous I/O. There is almost zero synchronous I/O in javascript (except console.log to the terminal in node.js - console.log makes your servers slow unless you pipe it to another process or socket). If other languages start doing this javascript will lose the speed advantage. Generally, when Java is able to beat node.js is when the framework uses Netty instead for I/O (asynchronous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has asynchronous operations.  But, a `for` loop is synchronous, not asynchronous.  The code you show doesn't use any asynchronous operations, therefore it's all synchronous.

> Should `myfunc()` execute in node and take longer, so that "end" should be invoked earlier because javascript is asynchronous?

No.  Nothing in `myfunc()` is asynchronous.  That's all synchronous  code in your question.

Operations such as `setTimeout()` or `http.get()` or `fs.readFile()` are all asynchronous operations.  They don't change the fact that the `for` loop runs synchronously, but the responses to any asynchronous you might put in the loop will happen AFTER your `console.log("end")` runs.

If you did something like this:

```
console.log("start")
myfunc()
console.log("end")

function myfunc(){
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
      setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(`timer ${i} done now`);
      }, 100);
  }
  console.log("this should be the end")
}
```

Would then show this output:

```
start
this should be the end
end
timer 0 done now
timer 1 done now
timer 2 done now
....
```

This is the sequence of operations:

1. output `console.log("start")`
2. call myfunc()
3. run the `for` loop starting 10 `setTimeout()` asynchronous operations
4. finish the `for` loop and output `console.log("this should be the end")`
5. `myfunc()` returns
6. Output `console.log("end")`
7. Some time later the first timer finishes and calls its callback and outputs `timer 0 done now`.
8. The rest of the timers finish
9. The `for` loop runs synchronously and starts all the timers and then `myfunc()` returns.

Comment: What if a put a HTTP request in that function?

Comment: The HTTP request would be asynchronous but the for loop would still be synchronous - it would **schedule** (not execute) the HTTP requests until all javascript execution has ended (reach end of script) then the interpreter will notice that there is nothing else to execute and will make the HTTP requests

Comment: @David - I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As `jfriend` noted, your code is purely synchronous. Here's what happens (very, very roughly):

- `console.log('start')` is added to the call stack -- it fires and then exits the call stack, and you see the provided message
- `myFunc` is added to the call stack (note that JavaScript is LIFO, or `last in, first out`)
- within the `myFunc` execution context, you have a `for` loop that iterates -- even though it doesn't explicitly do anything, it implicitly does a variety of things, including variable assignment, comparison, and incrementation -- all of which happen one after the other (synchronous behavior)
- after the loop completes, `console.log('this should be the end')` is added to the call stack (still within the `myFunc` execution context), and it logs to the console and then exits the call stack
- next, `myFunc` exits the call stack
- finally, `console.log('end')` enters the call stack, fires, and then exits the call stack

If you wanted to see asynchronous behavior in action, there are APIs you can use. `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, I/O operations, promises (and `async/await`), for example.